# Mismatching kernel versions during installation inside chroot

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, chroot, modprobe, artix-linux

I'm trying to install Artix on a QEMU virtual machine through an automated script i've wrote, in one of the latest installation steps, where i setup Rootless Docker, it's required to enable the `ip_tables` kernel module by running `modprobe ip_tables` inside the installation mount point with `chroot`

The problem is that i get the following error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory `/lib/modules/5.13.4-artix1-1
```

After some further inspection, i've noticed that `pacman -Q linux` returns versions `5.16.10-artix1-1`, and the versions on my `/lib/modules` is `5.13.4-artix1-1`

Does `chroot` has anything to do with that? or the problem lies somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Artix installation process gave the new installation the most up-to-date kernel version that was available in the Artix repository, not the outdated one from the boot media.

Just running

```
modprobe ip_tables
```

will not persist over a reboot anyway; you (or your script) should instead add persistent configuration to load the module at every system reboot, finalize the rest of the Artix installation if you have not yet done so, and set up a (second) script that will continue setting up Docker the first time the system boots on its own. The second script should then remove/disable itself after it's done it's job.

Then exit the chroot and reboot the VM. You're basically reaching the end of what you can conveniently do in the installer environment before the new OS installation is actually running.

Comment: What would be the recommended way of loading a kernel module on boot? (on a non-systemd environment)

Comment: Looks like creating a `/etc/modules-load.d/some-descriptive-name.conf` file with the name(s) of module(s) to load (one per line) should always work, regardless of whether or not systemd is used.